# Estructura para proyecto en Django

Tags: python, django

¿Cuál es la estructura recomendada para crear un proyecto?

```
/proyecto
/app01
/app02
manage.py
```

Tengo 3 dudas:

- Una aplicación (app) ¿es considerada un módulo en el proyecto?
- ¿Qué es un módulo en Django?
- ¿Qué es un aplicación en Django?

Comment: Esta podría ser una buena pregunta, pero al no haber un estándar, la recomendación depende de opiniones. Luego, no se plantea un problema en particular y no hay evidencia de que se haya consultado la documentación. Propongo que se modifique para plantear un problema o que se cierre.

Comment: Punto a favor: Es una pregunta que denota preocupación por mantener ordenado y estandarizada su aplicación y que puede servir a los demás.    Punto en contra: se nota que no hay investigación en su consulta.Propongo loo mismo que @toledano

Comment: Reabranla, yo tengo una respuesta!!! jajajaa
@toledano usted puede modificarla, replantearla, para poder responderla de mejor manera. Por favor.

Answer (score 3):

Para crear un proyecto Django lo mejor es que utilices simplemente el comando `startproject`, que ya dispone toda la estructura para que empieces a trabajar.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#startproject

```
django-admin startproject NUEVO_PROYECTO /home/andres/Dev/nuevo_proyecto
```

Tienes un comando parecido para crear una aplicación nueva.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#startapp

Desde el directorio del proyecto, este comando te crea una aplicación nueva:

```
python manage.py startapp mi_app
```

Comment: Hola @AndresVilca si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.